# No Data collected in the sitecore Reporting Database

Tags: reporting

I can see the users are being added in the Experience profile but my analytics chart doesn't show any data.

I checked the reporting database and it is empty.

I have spent more time in troubleshooting. Can any one help out on this?

1. I added @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
2. I have disabled Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots and Analytics.AutoDetectBots

   ```
   setting name="Analytics.AutoDetectBots" set:value="false
   setting name="Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots" set:value="false"
   ```
3. I had checked my solr URL and it doesn't contain any # symbol in the path
4. I have set IndexAnonymousContactData in 2 of my configs true
   IndexAnonymousContactData true  IndexAnonymousContactData
5. When I add the profile programmatically I can see the visits to ExperienceProfile and no entries in reporting database. Even the websites I have is not populated in filter as you can see in the image:

[image]

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: Its sitecore 9.2 Chris

Comment: Can you open the databases Xdb.Collection.Shard0.Contacts and Interactions and see if you have some recent entries.

Comment: In the contacts table I can see all the latest contacts . In the ineraction table I can see only intraction that I have added using the custom code

Comment: Any errors in Sitecore logs like "Tracker is not initialized"

Comment: I checked and this error message was not found. I can see below error message repetedly "Access to the registry key 'Global' is denied". Is this some thing related to issue

Comment: There was a patch that sitecore released concerning devices. See in your logs, if there are errors `Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.EntityOperationException
Message: Operation #0, Conflict, DeviceProfile`. If yes, maybe this might help https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/241788

Comment: Once you changed IndexAnonymousContactData to true, did you restart xConnect and the processing windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted out the issue. The Default Global.asax was replaced by the file that was deployed in the code. This was the reason for the issue

I have replaced the default Global.asax

Once Done I have restarted My VM and My Analytics was up!

[image]